# Geometry -- intersect of 2 circles and 1 polygon

Tags: geometry

[image: Situation]

How to compute **green area**?

Is there known procedure to compute intersect area of **2..n circles** and **1 arbitrary polygon** (exclude self-intersect polygons)?

Comment: Note half-planes are like really, Really, BIG circles.  You might consider circles only first.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can I imagine polygon as a circle?

Comment: You can approximate it arbitrarily closely by an intersection of circles (disks).

Comment: Isn't this trivial? Specifically, can't you compute the locations of the vertices on the perimeter of the region (which amounts to solving quadratic equations) and dissect the region into triangles and curvilinear digons, the areas of which are easily computed?

Answer (score 0):

First compute the points of intersection. To intersect a circle with a line, you can describe a generic point on the line as $a+\lambda b$ for $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, $a$ any point on the line and $b$ the direction of the line. Plugging this formula into the equation of the circle will give an equation quadratic in $\lambda$. To intersect two circles, you can subtract their equations to obtain a linear equation which you can again interpret as the equation of a line. Once you have these coordinates, you can describe the colored area as the sum of a triangle and two [circular segments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment).

With respect to generic approaches: [CGAL Arrangements](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/index.html) compute intersections by splitting the outlines of shapes into pieces which are easy to describe and monotonous in $x$. In its current version it [doesn't compute areas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20215451/1468366), but there is no principal problem against that.